# ng-repeat not displaying data from function

Tags: angularjs

I am following a basic tutorial on Angular from http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_filters_uppercase 
I wanted to change the string array within the controller to the return of a function to make it dynamic but data are not displayed.
I have found some similar questions and answers but no answer helped me. I know there is some tric with the ng-init to use but i can not get it.

Here is my code :

```
            <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">

            <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="x in names ">
                {{ x }}
            </li>
            </ul>

            </div>

            <script>
            angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
                $scope.names =  someFunction(10);
            });

            function someFunction(param) {
                var result = [];
                result.push("a");
                for(i = 1; i<= param; i++){
                ruban.push("b");
                } 
                return result;
            }
            </script>

            </body>
            </html>
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Is it displaying anything, in the view or the console? If you just put `{{names}}` in the view, does it display anything that looks valid?

Comment: What is `ruban.push("b");` ? I don't see "ruban" anywhere else in your  code

Comment: I agree with Alex; if you open your developer tools, I bet you'll see something like `ReferenceError: ruban is not defined`.  Also, make sure you don't end up with a duplication error for ng-repeat -- I recommend using `<li ng-repeat="x in names track by $index">`

Comment: @Harris, thank you for your answer. It is displaying nothing in the view for an argument (of the function)  greater than 0 ( for param = 0, it works  by dispalying the letter 'a'). And when i just put   {{names}} in the view it displays it exactly as i wrote it ({{names}}).

Comment: @Alex and Brent, you are right. i wrote named the variable ruban for the first time before changing it to 'result'. Now when i fixed the name nothing is new to my comment to Harris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ng-repeat requires unique values.  The way to accomplish that in your case is to do this:

```
<li ng-repeat="x in names track by $index">
```

That and fix this line in your func:

```
ruban.push("b");
```

to be:

```
result.push("b");
```

And move someFunction() into your controller, then declare it before calling it.  Like this:

```
.controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {

  function someFunction(param) {
    var result = [];
    result.push('a');

    for (i = 1; i <= param; i++) {
      result.push('b');
    }
    return result;
  }

  $scope.names = someFunction(10);
});
```

Comment: I think you meant to correct it to `result.push("b");`.

Comment: Yes I did @HarrisWeinstein.  Thanks.

Comment: @jbrown Good catch

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, try removing/changing the "ruban.push()" and make sure you use "track by" for your ng-repeat.

Can you try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">

        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="x in names track by $index">
                {{ x }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script>
    angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.names =  someFunction(10);
    });

    function someFunction(param) {
        var result = [];
        result.push("a");
        for(i = 1; i<= param; i++){
        result.push("b");
        } 
        return result;
    }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you @Brent, it is solved by jbrown exactly like this way.